# asp.net core route specific middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I was working with KOA 2.0 and started to test asp.net core. But can't find a way to handle request/url specific middleware

Say in Koa, with router I can achieve the below:

```
.post("/api/v1/user", Middleware1, Middleware2, RequestValidationMiddleware, SpecificAction);
.get("/api/v1/user", Middleware1, Middleware2, RequestValidationMiddleware, SpecificAction1);
.post("/api/v1/role", Middleware1, Middleware4, RequestValidationMiddleware2, SpecificAction2);
```

How to achieve it with asp.net core?

Tried the below:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    //app.UseApiLog();
    app.Map("/api", ApiLogApps);
    app.Map("/exlog", ExceptionLogApps);

    //app.UseMvc(routes =>
    //{
    //    routes.MapRoute(
    //                    name: "default",
    //                    template: "apilog/{controller}/{action}");
    //    routes.MapRoute(
    //                    name: "default2",
    //                    template: "exlog/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id:int}");
    //});
}

private static void ApiLogApps(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    //app.Run(() => )
    app.UseApiLog();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

And in controller I have

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("test/get/{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

But I am lost here.

What I want is, I want to have DataValidation to be handled in a middleware - that forces me to have per url (almost) specific middleware.

PS - I know, model validation can be done in action, but I don't want that.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: In .net core sense of middlewares, middleware runs early - before the route is known. Each middleware is used for each request. For what you want, you can use action filters. Action filters can have services injected into them - and will most likely be sufficient for you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To use middlewares like Koa2 , you can configure a sequence of middlewares to build a route :

```
    public IRouter BuildRouter(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
    {
        var builder = new RouteBuilder(applicationBuilder);

        // use middlewares to configure a route
        builder.MapMiddlewareGet("/api/v1/user", appBuilder => {
            // your Middleware1
            appBuilder.Use(Middleware1);
            appBuilder.Use(Middleware2);
            appBuilder.Use(RequestValidationMiddleware);
            appBuilder.Run(SpecificAction);
        });

        builder.MapMiddlewarePost("/api/v1/user", appBuilder => {
            // your Middleware1
            appBuilder.Use(Middleware1);
            appBuilder.Use(Middleware2);
            appBuilder.Use(RequestValidationMiddleware);
            appBuilder.Run(SpecificAction1);
        });
        // ....

        return builder.Build();
    }
```

and then use RouterMiddleware via `UseRouter(router)` :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // ...
    app.UseRouter(BuildRouter(app));
    // ...
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

a screenshot:

[image]

[Update]:

To integrate with attribute routing, just add a `UseMvc()` insteand of `Run()` as below :

```
    public IRouter BuildRouter(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
    {
        var builder = new RouteBuilder(applicationBuilder);

        // use middlewares to configure a route
        builder.MapMiddlewareGet("/api/v1/user", appBuilder => {
            appBuilder.Use(Middleware1);
            appBuilder.Use(Middleware2);
            appBuilder.Use(RequestValidationMiddleware);
            appBuilder.UseMvc();          // use a MVC here ...
        });

        builder.MapMiddlewarePost("/api/v1/user", appBuilder => {
            appBuilder.Use(Middleware1);
            appBuilder.Use(Middleware2);
            appBuilder.Use(RequestValidationMiddleware);
            appBuilder.UseMvc();
        });
        // ....

        return builder.Build();
    }
```

Just for a demo , the Middleware1 is a dummy middleware that adds a `HttpContext.Items['mw-message1']`:

```
    private Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate> Middleware1 = next=> {
        return async context =>
        {
            context.Items["mw-message1"] = "mw1";
            await next(context);
        };
    };
```

the Controller is a plain controller that will retrieve the `HttpContext.Items["mw-messages1"]`:

```
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var x = (string)HttpContext.Items["mw-message1"];
        return new JsonResult(new {
            MW1 = x,
            Hello= "Hello",
        });
    }
}
```

and now , when make a Get request to `/api/v1/user` , the final response is :

```
{"mW1":"mw1","hello":"Hello"}
```

Comment: thank you. I have another question... can I integrate with attribute routing ... `[Route("api/v1/user")]` annotation in UserController? If yes, then please help me out.

Comment: @IndrajitDan I've updated the answer . To do that , just replace the `Run(SpecificAction1)` with `UseMvc()` .  However , I don't think it is a best practice . As far as I know , It's better to use Mvc Filters and ModelBinders .

Comment: Note that this won't work with endpoint routing in ASP.NET Core 3.0+ (since `UseEndpoints` cannot be called on branched pipeline). As far as I know this can be tackled by using `app.UseWhen(c => c.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/foo"), ...` which rejoins back to the main pipeline.

Comment: @HonzaR, you right :( and this fixed only in 5.0rc https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/25714

Answer (score 3):

I am using below code in for .net core 3 webapi.

add below in startup.cs configure method to add middleware for specific route

//Middleware to check Authorization key is present in the request header
//Map to all routes

```
_ = app.UseHeaderKeyAuthorization();
```

//Map to all routes

```
_ = app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api/v1.0"), appBuilder =>
{
    _ = appBuilder.UseHeaderKeyAuthorization();
});
```

create middleware HeaderKeyAuthorizationMiddleware, sample below

```
//HeaderKeyAuthorizationMiddleware
public class HeaderKeyAuthorizationMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;

        public HeaderKeyAuthorizationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            this.next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var authHeader = httpContext.Request.Headers[ApiConstants.AuthHeaderName];
            //check authHeader logic
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authHeader))
            {
                await next.Invoke(httpContext);
                return;
            }

            //Reject request if there is no authorization header or if it is not valid
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized");
        }
    }

//Middleware extension to register middleware   
public static class HeaderKeyAuthorizationMiddlewareExtension
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseHeaderKeyAuthorization(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            if (app == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
            }

            return app.UseMiddleware<HeaderKeyAuthorizationMiddleware>();
        }
    }
```