# Route Specific Middleware - NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-core

I've used Laravel to build web apps, but now I'm trying to learn ASP.NET CORE. I need to create a custom middleware and apply it to an action of a controller. How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Could you be a tad more specific? Based on your requirements an actionfilter might be more suitable then custom middleware

Comment: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: I need to create a middleware to check if user is logged when he goes to some controller actions. I need to check if user is logged using my DBContext and taking data from Session.

Answer (score 0):

In .net core sense of middlewares, middleware runs early - before the route is known. Each middleware is used for each request. For what you want, you can use action filters. Action filters can have services injected into them - and will most likely be sufficient for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51955806/asp-net-core-route-specific-middleware/)!

Answer (score 0):

Taking the middleware specific approach in .NET Core 3.1, we can conditionally add middleware using the following-
In configure method-

app.UseWhen(context=>context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("your-route-url"),branch=>branch.useMiddleware(););

There are a few ways how the pipeline branching can happen, follow the docs for more information-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#branch-the-middleware-pipeline