# Attaching middleware to a specific route in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Inside the `configure`, I can attach a global middleware using:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   ....
   app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
   ...
}
```

This will apply to all actions.

However, I thought to myself, how can I attach a middleware to a specific route/action? (*Sure I can put some if's inside the code but I don't like the approach*)

But then I saw this:

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
      endpoints.Map("/version", endpoints.CreateApplicationBuilder()
               .UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>()
               .UseMiddleware<VersionMiddleware>()
               .Build())
               .WithDisplayName("Version number"); 
  }
```

This will work but will create a NEW endpoint `/version`.

**Question**

How can I attach custom middleware to an existing controller action route?

I've tried:

```
endpoints.Map("/weatherforecast", endpoints.CreateApplicationBuilder()
    .UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>()
    .UseMiddleware<VersionMiddleware>()
    .Build())
    .WithDisplayName("Version number");
```

But it doesn't seem to affect. I see a regular response from the controller. Without new headers which the middleware adds.

Comment: why not create common middleware and filter route there?

Comment: @zolty13 as I've written : _(Sure I can put some if's inside the code but I don't like the approach)_. I believe there is another way

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51955806/asp-net-core-route-specific-middleware is this helpful for you?

Comment: @zolty13 I'm wondering , reading the answer in the link , will `app.UseRouter(BuildRouter(app));` override ALL other routes ? in other words , is it an addition or replacement ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the MapWhen

https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/conditional-middleware-based-on-request-in-asp.net-core

from the link, modified:

```
app.UseMiddlewareOne();

app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/version", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)), appBuilder =>
{
    appBuilder.UseMiddlewareTwo();
});

app.UseMiddlewareThree();
```

Comment: [I've tried it](https://i.imgur.com/RcN7h1C.jpg) , but I get an [error](https://i.imgur.com/RBJAUeY.jpg) . [this is my middleware](https://i.imgur.com/cVR5WlU.jpg)

Comment: that problem is not because of when your middleware is used I think but later in your configure method, it tells you that nothing handled given case. Did you include in your UseEndpoints delegate for instance endpoints.MapControllers();endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute() ?

Comment: yes i did :https://i.imgur.com/rZtvRfm.jpg. stil same error. I think I know what's happening here. In the middleware I'm actually calling `next` (https://i.imgur.com/tIEH2vX.jpg). but there is no next pipe actually. however if I [short circuit](https://i.imgur.com/Hb6C2V2.jpg) it , [then it does work](https://i.imgur.com/r0OgkA0.jpg). it make sense since there is no delegate to invoke after this middleware. Whenmap open a branch(!). not a an addition but as a new branch. so no other future middleware available for him to `next()`. Am I right ?

Comment: When you use MapWhen and condition is true next middleware will not run. You can use UseWhen if you want to run next middleware.

Comment: @bugrakosen regardin  my last comment here ^ ,  is my assumoption correct ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir yes you are right. If you don't want short circuit you can use `if(_next != null) await _next(context)`

Comment: @bugrakosen it doesn't work. still the same xception.... https://i.imgur.com/ZSvCDrF.jpg , here is the startup : https://i.imgur.com/djMvtVv.jpg .........https://i.imgur.com/fWxGEzd.jpg

Comment: @RoyiNamir I realized, when you use MapWhen and if condition is true _next delegate declaring type is ApplicationBuilder. `_next != null` approach not work some how. I did `if(_next.Target.GetType().DeclaringType != typeof(ApplicationBuilder)) await _next(context)` and it works. That is not the best solution but it's a solution :) If you wanna run the next middlewares, use UseWhen anyway.

Comment: Not sure exactly but you're adding the header @RoyiNamir when the request is the same like the single controller you have so depending on what your default method is doesn't it get around that when launching or just navigating to? in which case no controller is there and it will do a flat GET / which doesn't have anything answering which is what it claims. Perhaps try adding comparison to StartsWithSegment, will update example